# Symfony2.1 production environment uses other timezone as test

Tags: php, symfony, deployment

The test and prod env of our sf2.1 application are hosted on the same server. The sourcecode of them both is similar, with exception of the custom `config_<env>.yml`

At first, the `dev` and `test` environment also had this problem. I solved it for those environments with the following snipped, so I assumed this should also work for the `prod` environment.

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
public function init()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
    parent::init();
}
```

Other things I tried

1. Clear environment caches
2. Upload a plain test.php file with var_dump(new \DateTime()). The correct time was dumped in all environments, so this is Symfony-specific

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the code instead of using the `php.ini`?

Comment: Because the php.ini is correct, since it works great on the test environment. The first thing I did was try to localize the problem, and it hasn't anything to do with Apache / PHP settings I think. Dumping a new DateTime outside Symfony results in the correct date on both the test and prod environment. So, the only place where the error occurs is in Symfony on the prod env.

Comment: The error only occurs in Symfony (Controllers, Doctrine, Twig). When I create a plain PHP file and dump a new DateTime("now"), the date is correct. Aside of that, the bug does not occur at the `test` environment, which is on the same server. So, that is why I don't understand where to debug this...